# Command line tool to draw very simple GUI windows?

Tags: gui, window-manager

I am using a GTK(3) based linux desktop environment (Linux Mint Cinnamon). Is there any tool that you can run from the terminal that draws a simple GTK window on the screen with just the essential tools like minimize, maximize and close.

I would like it to display some basic messages, like a "hello world" (or pipe in the output of another command) or a menu, and then have the user provide some input and the window simply conveys this input to some other program/script.